# how to make button disabled in php?

Tags: php, jquery

my question is how to make button disabled?
            I have two buttons on/off,i had already stored as off in table..when the users wants him to update the table,the webpage will display as the disabled button of off button.

Comment: Like this `<?php echo '<button disabled>I am disabled!</button>'; ?>`

Comment: good @jeremy,but my question is when the matched value of database is to disable the button on webpage..

Comment: Dude, show what you tried, and what error you get. Also clearify your question.
You take value from database and making button on/off depending on that value? Is it right?

Comment: yes@ SHAZ even i don't get a error

Comment: Your question was "How do I make a disabled button in PHP". Given you didn't provide any context or any code, I answered consequently :)

Comment: its@jeremy Thille just like that my program is two button on/off..when i click the button on it will store into db as on otherwise off..and then when user want to update this what it had already stored is make the button disable and enable the other button... this is my code dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code:

```
<?php
  $db_value = true or false; // put your database retrieved value here
  if($db_value == true ):
    echo '<button type="button" name ="myButton" disabled>OFF</button>'; 
  else:
    echo '<button type="button" name ="myButton">ON</button>'; 
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer@ shaz...and my another question is make it another button enable..

Comment: See updated answer. If helpfull accept and upvote it. @navas

Comment: hi@SHAZ how to enable the other button.

Comment: other button means? Explain some details please

Comment: like on/off..if i click the on button it makes disable and make the off button disable

Comment: @navas , for this you use toggleClass function in jquery. its simple google it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching data using query you can achieve this as like

```
<input type='button' value='button' <?php if($data === "off"){echo "disabled";}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

'Try something like this:

```
<?php
$x=1;  //says "on" is 1 and "off" is 0 in your database value.here you can check your database value and apply condition accordingly
if($x==1) { 
$disabled="disabled=true"; 
} else { 
$disabled=""; 
}
echo '<input type="button" name="button" value="button" '.$disabled.'>';
?>
```

Comment: @navas this will help you :) Enjoy ur day

Comment: reason to downvote my answer?

Comment: Sure: [having the sole `disabled` attribute by itself makes the field disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp). Setting it to `false` won't make it enabled, neither do you need to set it to `true`. Actually, `disabled="disabled"` is best way to do it as it is XHTML compliant.